# Issue with Cloning Player Characters in Roblox Studio(Lua)

Tags: lua, roblox, roblox-studio

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am currently facing an issue with a script in Roblox Studio, where I am attempting to duplicate a player's character upon joining the game. The primary objective is to clone the player's character and relocate the duplicate to a specific position.

Despite my efforts, the character cloning process doesn't seem to be working as intended. I've added a warning message to help identify the problem, and it consistently outputs "Failed to clone character for player [PlayerName]." I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully duplicate the player's character.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I have currently tried a few different things but this is the best that I've gotten:

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(character)
        local humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
        local newCharacter = character:Clone()
        if newCharacter then
            newCharacter.Parent = workspace
            newCharacter:MoveTo(Vector3.new(0, 10, 0))
        else
            warn("Failed to clone character for player " .. player.Name)
        end
    end)
end)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found [this page](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/how-would-i-create-a-clone-of-a-player-in-game/904099) which seems to have the exact same problem as you.

The relevant code:

```
function CloneMe(char) --a function that clones a player
   char.Archivable = true
   local clone = char:Clone()
   char.Archivable = false
   return clone
end
```

Basically you can’t clone anything unless it has Archivable=true, and player characters have it disabled by default